# QTimer in a thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qtimer

I just merely want to emit 2 signal and a Qtimer timeout on button click from a GUI.

Although 2 SIGNAL/SLOT WORKS the QTimer's SIGNAL/SLOT is not working, the whentimeout SLOT never works.
There is no error even.

**GUI(DIALOG.CPP)**

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    fduthread = new fdustatus(this);
    connect(fduthread,SIGNAL(NumberChanged(int)),this,SLOT(onNumberChanged(int)));
    connect(fduthread,SIGNAL(nameChange(QString)),this,SLOT(onNameChanged(QString)));
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::onNumberChanged(int number)
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(number));
}

void Dialog::onNameChanged(QString s)
{

    ui->label_2->setText(s);

}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    fduthread->start();
    fduthread->stop=false;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ui->label_2->setText("");
    fduthread->stop=true;
}
```

---

THAT IS MY THREAD

```
#include "fdustatus.h"
#include<QMutex>
#include<QTimer>
#include<QDebug>

fdustatus::fdustatus(QObject *parent):QThread(parent)
{

}
void fdustatus::run()
{
   mytimer = new QTimer();
   mytimer->setInterval(10);
    connect( mytimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(whentimeout()));
     mytimer->start();
    for(int i =0;i<100;i++)
    {
        QMutex mutex;
        mutex.lock();
        if(this->stop)break;
        mutex.unlock();

        emit NumberChanged(i*10);

        emit nameChange(getstring());
        this->msleep(100);
   }

}
QString fdustatus::getstring()
{

    QString networkport;
    networkport.append("Alarm Active");
    return networkport;
}
void fdustatus::whentimeout()
{
    qDebug() << "timer ended from thread..";

}
```

Comment: I tried as you told. Even i tweaked the value of stop & check but the same issue exists.Just for checking I added  qDebug()<< mytimer->isActive(); at the end of run() and as expected it says true;

Comment: For loop will be broken on_pushButton_2_clicked() ,until it is not clicked in every 10 msec whentimeout() should be signalled.But, it's  is not happening here .

Comment: Nope ! even changing the thread affinity yields the same result!

Comment: It is nice tutorial [timer and threads](http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/) to use QTimer and QThread. You should consider to use moveToThread or call QThread::exec() to process events loop.

Comment: thanx,i will go through it and come back if any issue

Comment: thanx, it worked with exec() ..although moveToThread did not solve it. nevertheless very informative

Comment: it works with `exec()` when you add it at the end of `run` method, so timeout cannot be executed concurrently with your for loop. If you want to do it you can create new `QThread t`, then call `mytimer->moveToThread(t);` and `timeout` slot will be called concurrently with for loop.

Comment: yes! thanx mate ! working perfectly !